# How to end user session on window close, PHP

Tags: php, session

First off, I'm very new to web development, and PHP / JQUERY etc.

In my website the user can log in, which sets some $_SESSION variables, and stores their username in an "active user" MYSQL table. If they manually logout, by clicking a "logout" button, all is well -- however, if they choose to close the browser window without logging out, the database is not updated.

I've seen that the javascript "onunload" event is not desirable, and I've seen mention of checking for inactivity. I don't understand how to check for anything once the browser has already been closed.

How can I go about ensuring the user's session is terminated, if they decide to close the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `dateTime` in database with `lastSeen` and check it, on every request, if user make a new request and the time difference is 10 minutes you log him out and redirect to login screen.

If you want to see how many active user on your site, you can make a query what is only show users who are seen in the last 10 minutes.

ps;: 10 minutes can be more or less of course.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Assuming I did this, where would this code be running? Like, how will these "last seen" checks be made, if the user already closed the browser? Or does this system rely, on at least 1 user being active to run the checks?

Comment: You can do that way, but I am strongly recommend to not have `active user"`table, just users with `last_seen`  field, and on the the server side implement some logic what is calculating the active user. How I mentioned before.

Comment: Please explain that last part, I did not know you could have "server side" logic. I can set up a script or something on SQL? How is this done, or where is something I can read that shows me how to set up logic on MYSQL?